# What's the name for sequences sitting between geometric and arithmetic, i.e. whose recurrence relation is of the form $ax+b$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, terminology, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

What's the name for sequences sitting between geometric and arithmetic?

E.g. let $x_{n+1}=ax_n+b$

I can't find a general name for these.

These sequences may also be a [Lucas Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) but that's a pretty convoluted way of defining these.

Comment: A linear recurrence relation?

Comment: @mrp looks like that generalises Lucas sequences too. I guess I can use that.

Comment: @JohnBentin as a counterexample I offer you $U(5,4)=1,5,21,85..$ which is a Lucas sequence of the first kind and also has the recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=4x_n+1$

Comment: @samerivertwice :  Agreed. The Lucas sequence $U(P,P-1)$, with initial terms $x_0$ and $x_1$  is also generated by $x_{n+1}=(P-1)x_n+x_1-(P-1)x_0$. Thank you for the correction. I will delete my wrong comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is [Linear recurrence Relations](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/#)

Answer (score 3):

In a french context they are called "suites arithmético-géométriques".

Answer (score 1):

The relations $x_{n+1}=ax_n+b\,$ ($n=0,1,...$), with $a$ and $b$ constant, describe a form of iterated affine transformation, and so the generated $x_0,x_1,...$ could be called an *affine sequence*. The iterative process has been called an *affine recursion*. You can do an internet search for this term, but I only found more advanced applications of this idea, to generate fractals or solve minimization problems in higher dimensions.